# Препроцессинг текста для обучения модели классификации в Keras

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, numpy, keras

Я написал скрипт нейронной сети, а точнее часть с подготовкой данных на вход. Но не уверен, правильно ли всё сделал для того, чтобы модель смогла корректно обучаться. Очень нужна оценка знающих людей.

**Код:**

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts


labels_lexicon = ['_label_0', '_label_1', '_label_2'] # список категорий

def get_data_from_the_file():
  labels, descriptions, lexicon, lexicon_base = [], [], [], []
  for i,  line in enumerate(open('testtext.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')):
    content = line.split()
    labels.append([content[0]])
    descriptions.append(content[1:])
    lexicon_base += content[1:]

  count_lexicon = Counter(lexicon_base).most_common(5000)
  for count_item in count_lexicon:
   lexicon.append(count_item[0])

  return labels, descriptions, lexicon

labels, descriptions, lexicon = get_data_from_the_file()

def get_descriptions_to_index(lexicon):
    cache = {}
    word2index = {}
    for i,word in enumerate(lexicon):
        if cache.get(word) == None:
            cache[word] = i
            word2index[word] = i
    return word2index
word2index = get_descriptions_to_index(lexicon)


def get_labels_to_index(labels_lexicon):
    cache = {}
    labels2index = {}
    for i,word in enumerate(labels_lexicon):
        if cache.get(word) == None:
            cache[word] = i
            labels2index[word] = i
    return labels2index
labels2index = get_labels_to_index(labels_lexicon)

list_of_tokenize_descriptions = []
list_of_tokenize_labels = []


for descriptions_arrays in descriptions:
    prepare_list_of_tokenize_descriptions = []
    for descriptions_piece in descriptions_arrays:
        if word2index.get(descriptions_piece) != None:
            prepare_list_of_tokenize_descriptions.append(word2index[descriptions_piece])
    list_of_tokenize_descriptions.append(prepare_list_of_tokenize_descriptions)


for labels_arrays in labels:
    prepare_list_of_tokenize_labels = []
    for labels_piece in labels_arrays:
        if labels2index.get(labels_piece) != None:
            prepare_list_of_tokenize_labels.append(labels2index[labels_piece])
    list_of_tokenize_labels.append(prepare_list_of_tokenize_labels)

x_matrix_list = []
y_matrix_list = []

for i in range(len(list_of_tokenize_descriptions)):
  matrix_i = np.zeros((len(lexicon)),dtype=int)
  line =  list_of_tokenize_descriptions[i]
  for index in line:
    matrix_i[index] = 1
  x_matrix_list.append(matrix_i)


for i in range(len(list_of_tokenize_labels)):
  matrix_i = np.zeros((len(labels_lexicon)),dtype=int)
  line =  list_of_tokenize_labels[i]
  for index in line:
    matrix_i[index] = 1
  y_matrix_list.append(matrix_i)


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = tts(np.array(x_matrix_list), np.array(y_matrix_list),  test_size=0.3)
```

Здесь ссылкуа на [dataset](https://yadi.sk/i/PuReYvbe_aLF4A).

Comment: Вы отметили ответ как принятый, но не отметили как полезный. Почему, может что-то не хватает в ответе? Вы можете написать комментарий с просьбой уточнить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы в данном случае воспользовался методом [keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def get_data(filename, num_words=5000, frac=1.0):
    data = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['text'], sep='~')
              .sample(frac=frac))
    data[['label','text']] = data.pop('text').str.split(n=1, expand=True)
    data = data.dropna()
    data = data.loc[data['label'].str.contains(r'^_label')]

    # build vocabulary
    tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)
    tok.fit_on_texts(data['text'])
    # convert texts to sequences
    X = tok.texts_to_sequences(data['text'])
    lb = LabelBinarizer()
    Y = pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(data['label']), 
                     columns=lb.classes_, index=data.index)
    return (pad_sequences(X, maxlen=num_words), Y, tok)


path = Path(r'D:\temp\.data')            
filename = path / 'testtext.txt'
num_words = 1000

X, Y, tok = get_data(filename, num_words=num_words)

# split data set to train / dev
X_train, X_dev, Y_train, Y_dev = \
    train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123, stratify=Y)
print('X_train.shape:\t{}\t\tY_train.shape:\t{}'.format(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape))
print('X_dev.shape:\t{}\t\tY_dev.shape:\t{}'.format(X_dev.shape, Y_dev.shape))
```

вывод:

```
X_train.shape:  (26850, 1000)           Y_train.shape:  (26850, 3)
X_dev.shape:    (6713, 1000)            Y_dev.shape:    (6713, 3)
```

Что у нас получилось:

```
In [4]: X
Out[4]:
array([[  0,   0,   0, ..., 250, 154,  16],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 112, 121,  84],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  72,  49,  44],
       ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   5, 109,  99],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 158, 513,  78],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0, 138]])

In [5]: X.shape
Out[5]: (33563, 1000)

In [6]: Y
Out[6]:
       _label_0  _label_1  _label_2
30455         1         0         0
19423         1         0         0
29907         0         1         0
12779         0         1         0
28342         0         0         1
27583         0         0         1
28096         0         1         0
21411         1         0         0
23425         1         0         0
33227         1         0         0
...         ...       ...       ...
28788         1         0         0
17329         0         1         0
5339          0         1         0
9461          0         0         1
31315         0         0         1
23199         1         0         0
6752          0         1         0
164           1         0         0
24283         0         0         1
25055         0         0         1

[33563 rows x 3 columns]

In [7]: Y.shape
Out[7]: (33563, 3)
```

---

```
In [10]: tok.index_word[250]
Out[10]: 'реабилитац'

In [11]: tok.index_word[154]
Out[11]: 'инвалид'

In [12]: tok.index_word[16]
Out[12]: 'год'
```