# Как векторизовать список предложений?

Tags: python, массивы, нейронные-сети, keras, вектор

Помогите, я не понимаю всех этих преобразований. Строю сеть классификатор. Есть список предложений и список тем, к которым они относятся. Как это все превратить в вектор, чтобы скормить нейронке? 
Вот так выглядит элемент списка с предложениями:
выборщик республиканец из техаса отказался голосовать за трампа
Вот так выглядит элемент списка тем:
politics

Comment: о каком языке программирования идет речь?

Comment: @MaxU о питоне, средствами keras сделать хочу сеть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Препроцессинг текста для обучения модели классификации в Keras](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/921572/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-keras)